# Does PostgreSQL implement Geospatial relationship queries?

Tags: postgresql, gis, geospatial

My company is looking at different database providers, and how they implement Geospatial queries to get distances from a Lat/Long for a number of records.

We are going to investigate PostgreSQL as a potential database platform.

- I've heard that PostGRE implements Geospatial queries.  Is this correct?
- Is there a good reference somewhere that gives info on the implementation?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/). For reference you have [manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1), [wiki](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiMain) and [more...](http://postgis.net/documentation/)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to spatially enable a PostgreSQL database you can do so with [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/), it's compliant with the Open Geospatial Consortium's [Simple Features Interface Standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfs) for SQL too.